# paths for searching executables

Tags: shell, software-installation, path

My old xournal is 0.4.5, which is `/usr/bin/xournal`. I just installed a new version 0.4.8 by compiling from source to `/usr/local/bin/xournal`.

When I call `xournal` directly from the terminal, it is the old version.

```
$ xournal
```

When I call `/usr/local/bin/xournal`, it is the new version.

```
$ /usr/local/bin/xournal
```

1. But `which` shows that `xournal` is `/usr/local/bin/xournal`

   ```
   $ which xournal
   /usr/local/bin/xournal
   ```

   Isn't `which` supposed to show the actual path when calling `xournal`?
2. My `PATH` puts `/usr/local/bin` before `/usr/bin`, so why doesn't
   calling `xournal`  call `/usr/local/bin/xournal` but
   `/usr/bin/xournal`?

   ```
   $ echo $PATH
   ”/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games”
   ```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just installed it it's likely that your shell has [cached](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Search-and-Execution) the old path. Use:

```
hash -r
```

to [clear the command hash table](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-hash) and then try running the command again.

Comment: thanks. by default, how often does it automatically rehash, without manually hashing?

Comment: The hash table lasts for the lifetime of your shell session, and is regenerated when you start a new shell.

Comment: Does `which` also search in some database or hashed results?

Comment: In some shells (not Bash), `which` is a builtin that uses the shell's hash table. The rest of the time it always searches `$PATH`.

Comment: where is the hashed relocation stored?

Comment: In memory. You can look at the current table with just `hash`. `type x` will tell you whether `x` is currently hashed or not.